# What are the computational complexities of Linear One-vs-One, Bayesian Multivariate, and k-NN algorithms?

Tags: classification, algorithms, model-evaluation, time-complexity

What are the computational complexities of

- Linear One-vs-One Committe,
- Bayesian multivariate with the class independence assumption, and
- k-NN algorithm with k=3?

In $\mathcal{O}$ (Big-O) notation?

Comment: You might want to provide some more background on what you mean by each of these terms.  One-vs-One is fairly well defined, but I'm not sure if "Linear One-vs-One" is, linear w.r.t. what?  Bayesian multivariate could be anything from multinomial probits to a multinomial-Dirichlet approach.  KNN speed depends on the data and algorithm; a fairly standard k-d tree approach would be $\mathcal{O}(n \log(n))$ for computational complexity, a naive approach would be quadratic.

Comment: @JonathanLisic, see the edit. That's all I know.

Comment: I should also mention for KNN with k-d trees, the $\mathcal{O}(n\log(n))$ is average computational complexity, worse case is again quadratic.  Locality-sensitive hashing is also competitive, but the computational complexity is more complex.